# Support multiple authentication types, both IdentityServer and Jwt token

Tags: asp.net, identityserver4, owin, claims-based-identity, bearer-token

A central service has IdentityServer  as the current authentication method which needs to stay intact.

Now another Jwt bearer token needs to be supported.

It seems possible to have the two token styles active at the same time, but I am unsure of when authentication checks run, and if both always run. Does the order matter? What happens if one of them fails?

During debugging of new token, the first block identity server authentication was commented out.

```
appBuilder.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new 
  IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
  {
    Authority = ...,
    ValidationMode = ValidationMode.Both,
    RequireHttps = ...,
    RequiredScopes = ...,
    AutomaticRefreshInterval = ...,
    ValidationResultCacheDuration = ...
  });

appBuilder.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
  //AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer,  // ???
  AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive, // what is best???  
  AllowedAudiences = new[] { audience },
  TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
      ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
      ValidateAudience = false,
      ValidateIssuer = false,
      IssuerSigningKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(secret),
      //ValidIssuer = issuer
      //ValidAudience = audience,
    }
  });
```

Current obstacle is we look for a ClaimsPrincipal, so can someone suggest where to create and add the ClaimsPrincipal?

For information:
Our Authorization check is implemented with `AuthorizationFilterAttribute`, see below code.

we only see a default `WindowsPrincipal` containing 1 `WindowsIdentities` of Anonymous kind

```
public override Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext ac, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (!(ac.RequestContext.Principal is ClaimsPrincipal p) 
|| !p.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
   {
      // we exit here with an Unauthorized since above Principal is not a of type ClaimsPrincipal
   }

    return Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

Comment: I would always put IdentityServer in its own service and then the API in a separate service instane , just to reduce the complexity that you otherwise get to make it work. => Separations of concerns...

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

The problem was that our configured values for `audience` and `issuer` were read as null, and the call to `appBuilder.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(` didn't seem to like nulls there.

There was no need to create a ClaimsPrincipal manually - the correct type just appeared automatically in the filter actionContext Request Principal once the configuration nulls were fixed.

Regarding the main question - whether multiple authentication providers could be setup after each other like above? Yes it works fine! We tested and you can authenticate with either an IdentityServer token and the new JwtBearer token.

The filter receives an `IsAuthenticated==true` principal token of type `ClaimsPrincipal` in both cases.

This was the finally working setup for the new Jwt token:

```
builder.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidIssuer = iss,
        ValidAudience = aud,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(secret),
    },
    AllowedAudiences = new[] { aud },
});
```